# Can't get RKPathMatcher pathMatcher to match for deleting orphans objects

Tags: ios, objective-c, core-data, restkit

I am having issues deleting my orphaned object the path matcher never matches. What should I use as path if the path contains 2 ids in the path. Thanks.

i.e /api/getEntity/1234/123  where 1234 is the parent id and 123 is the entity id

The request block is below:

```
  NSMutableURLRequest *request = [NSMutableURLRequest
 requestWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:formattedUrl]];
     [sharedManager addFetchRequestBlock:^NSFetchRequest *(NSURL *URL) {

        RKPathMatcher *pathMatcher = [RKPathMatcher pathMatcherWithPattern::@"/api/getEntity/all/:parentEntityId/:entityId/"];         NSDictionary *argsDict = nil;
        BOOL match = [pathMatcher matchesPath:[URL relativePath] tokenizeQueryStrings:NO parsedArguments:&argsDict];
        if(match){
            NSFetchRequest *fetchRequest = [[NSFetchRequest alloc] init];
            NSEntityDescription *entity = [NSEntityDescription entityForName:@"SomeEntity" inManagedObjectContext:[RKManagedObjectStore
 defaultStore].mainQueueManagedObjectContext];
             [fetchRequest setEntity:entity];             return fetchRequest;
        }
        return nil;
    }];
```

Comment: Looks generally ok, it has an `all` that the question doesn't have and a trailing slash may cause problems so you should remove that.

Comment: Yeah I missed that at the top. The url is /api/getEntity/all/1234/123/  the id in the parent entity is parentEntityId and the id in the entity is entityId .

Comment: So did you try removing the trailing slash? Have you logged the URL and relative path? Debugged the matching process?

Comment: The slash after the :entityId/ ?

Comment: Yes - is that actually in the URL path, usually not...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This looks like a mismatch in the URL path that you will be loading and the matcher spec of `/api/getEntity/all/:parentEntityId/:entityId/`, because you generally don't put a trailing slash on the URL as that denotes a directory and you're actually loading a 'page'. Slashes and therefore structure are important to the matcher.

So, remove the trailing slash.

Generally speaking your base URL should have a trailing slash and all of your path patterns should not have leading or trailing slashes.